# Strange Date Format behaviour with Xperia devices in Android

Tags: android, date, simpledateformat

I'm facing a real issue with date parsing in Android.
I'm receiving via JSON a date with dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm z format, all I need is to get the "localized" hour and minute and display it in my app.
With my code everything is working fine on every device, but my clients reported me that they CAN'T see the timings in the app when using a Sony XPERIA device.
They also told me that they had a XPeria device which couldn't display time, then they rooted it and everything started to work FINE. So I think it's something related so some strange implementation of the Date/simpledateformat/locale/timezone of sony's operative system.
Here's my code.

```
getDateLocalized("18/06/2012 18:00 CEST","HH:mm");

public static String getDateLocalized(String match_date, String pattern) {
    String d = "";
    String format = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm z";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = getSimpleDateFormat();
    try {
        Date date = sdf.parse(match_date);
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        sdf.applyLocalizedPattern(pattern);
        d = sdf.format(date);
        sdf.applyLocalizedPattern(format);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return d;
}

private static SimpleDateFormat getSimpleDateFormat() {
    String format = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm z";
    if (simpledateformat == null)
        simpledateformat = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.UK);
    return simpledateformat;
}
```

I'm using a singleton pattern to retrieve the SimpleDateFormat object since its creation is really expensive, and I'm displaying a high number of timings at the same time. I'm using Locale.UK since the LANGUAGE of the input date is English.

Big problem is that i DON'T have any sony xperia device to test it with :(

Thanks in advice

Comment: i would recommend to use Locale.ENGLISH intead of Locale.UK.Not sure if it will work.

Comment: thanks, I'll give it a try, it will take me a while to have it tested. Any other ideas? :)

Comment: it doesn't work with Locale.ENGLISH. Got parse problems with CEST.

Comment: Can you be specific on which Xperia devices you see this problem?

Comment: Almost all sony devices. For sure I know Xperia Play, but there are others. I'll check it out and let you know

Answer (score 0):

Issue is not basically with Xperia devices I think the issue with the default formatter. When we get Calender.getInstance().getTime() is display the proper date and when we do the formatting all the mess happens. Dont know why so put a patch for that and works for me.

```
 if(formattedDate.contains("HH")){
                int hris = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                formattedDate = formattedDate.replace("HH", ""+hris);

            }
```